# How to append text to the end of a certain line of a file?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

If I needed to append a username to the end line 32 on a file, how would I do so?

I can find on Google how to add text to the beginning of a line with `sed`, but I can't figure out how I would append it to the end, or even the middle, if that was possible.

Comment: By “the middle” do you mean the exact center of the line (with an even length)? Or just some position between the beginning and the end? In this case, how do you determine it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can substitute your text for the line end (`$`) like this:

```
sed -e '32s/$/your_text/' file
```

To insert text in the middle of the line some information about the line structure would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sed  '32s,$,SOMETHING TO ADD,' FILE
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v username='some username' -v line=32 'NR == line { $0 = $0 username } 1' file
```

To insert the username into the middle of the line, one would have to know more about what the lines in the file looks like.

If the username and line are variables:

```
awk -v username="$username" -v line="$line" 'NR == line { $0 = $0 username } 1' file
```

If you want to insert a space before the username:

```
awk -v username="$username" -v line="$line" 'NR == line { $0 = $0 " " username } 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed`:

```
$ seq 100 > 100file
$ username=jeff
$ ed -s 100file <<< $'32s/$/'"$username"$'/\nw\nq'
$ sed -n 28,34p 100file
28
29
30
31
32jeff
33
34
```

The trailing `/` of the replacement string suppresses the default-print behavior.