# Sed is not replacing with the value of a variable

Tags: linux, sed, variable

I'm using sed to modify a file. In simple terms, my modifier looks as so

```
sed -e '11s/$/ $LinuxUsername/'
```

This is suppose to add in their linux username at the end of line 11, however, it is instead posting the actual variable name "$LinuxUsername" at the end of line 11. How can i make it post the actual value of the variable?

I've tried using quotes and double quotes in different parts of the expression, but still failed to get it to work properly.

Currently, line 11 is looking like the following...

```
  john.doe william.mcmillion jonny.doeboy $LinuxUsername $LinuxUsername
```

**Edit**

The following is correct. Error was found further upstream.

```
sed -e "11s/$/ $LinuxUsername/"
```

Comment: [Answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477890/expand-variables-in-sed)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400447/170373 (I can't believe I can't find a more appropriate duplicate question)

Comment: Linking in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400447/117549

Comment: sed -e '11s/$/ $LinuxUsername/'
sed -e "11s/$/ $LinuxUsername/"
sed -e "11s/$/ \$LinuxUsername/"
All yield the same results, am i misunderstanding this?

Comment: That 2nd one should have put the contents of that variable at the end of the line. Is the variable populated?

Comment: Notice that when you asked https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/450647/117549, you didn't say that the username was a variable, so while you got *an* answer, you didn't get *the* answer to your real problem.

Comment: The 2nd one is correct, it seems the error was the populated variable as you have mentioned, it was getting replaced with its own name further upstream in the code.

Thanks you for the help, sorry for the unneeded question.